Interpretation of interaction results when regression coefficients are significant but average marginal effects are not
I am analysing results of an experimental study with three treatment groups using a gamma hurdle model with glmmTMB package in R. To facilitate the interpretation of coefficients, I want to report the average marginal effects, but as it's my first time working with these estimates, I have some trouble understanding them.
In the hurdle model below we can see that while the treatment (TIP_PISMA) has no significant effect on the dependent variable, there is a significant interaction between the treatment and another categorical covariate (KOPOP) in the conditional (gamma) part of the model:
summary(m2023_a)
Family: Gamma  ( log )
Formula:          ha_vpisanih ~ TIP_PISMA + OBMOCJE + TIP_PISMA * PRESEK_NJIVE +  
   NOSILEC_STAR + NOSILEC_SPOL + KOPOP * TIP_PISMA + obtezba
Zero inflation:               ~.
Data: podatki

    AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 1053.4   1251.4   -493.7    987.4     2940 


Dispersion estimate for Gamma family (sigma^2): 0.331 

Conditional model:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 -0.288084   0.486016  -0.593  0.55335    
TIP_PISMA1                   0.340293   0.442525   0.769  0.44190    
TIP_PISMA2                  -0.432615   0.321626  -1.345  0.17860    
OBMOCJEKrsko brezisko polje  0.415327   0.314855   1.319  0.18713    
OBMOCJELjubljanska kotlina   0.178324   0.378191   0.472  0.63727    
OBMOCJELjubljansko barje     0.601925   0.650455   0.925  0.35476    
OBMOCJEPomurje               0.634549   0.286056   2.218  0.02654 *  
PRESEK_NJIVE                 0.047465   0.007118   6.668  2.6e-11 ***
NOSILEC_STAR                 0.008110   0.005912   1.372  0.17014    
NOSILEC_SPOLŽ                0.191554   0.198733   0.964  0.33511    
KOPOP                       -0.070009   0.332004  -0.211  0.83299    
obtezba                      0.001140   0.001915   0.595  0.55163    
TIP_PISMA1:PRESEK_NJIVE     -0.024208   0.008986  -2.694  0.00706 ** 
TIP_PISMA2:PRESEK_NJIVE     -0.024964   0.008856  -2.819  0.00482 ** 
TIP_PISMA1:KOPOP             0.652561   0.525729   1.241  0.21451    
TIP_PISMA2:KOPOP             1.324987   0.415824   3.186  0.00144 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  5.7408388  0.8330739   6.891 5.53e-12 ***
TIP_PISMA1                   0.7409163  0.7127174   1.040   0.2985    
TIP_PISMA2                  -0.6211401  0.5151101  -1.206   0.2279    
OBMOCJEKrsko brezisko polje -2.4557714  0.4996001  -4.915 8.86e-07 ***
OBMOCJELjubljanska kotlina  -1.4629154  0.5879655  -2.488   0.0128 *  
OBMOCJELjubljansko barje     0.3632105  1.0910349   0.333   0.7392    
OBMOCJEPomurje              -0.7574541  0.4520394  -1.676   0.0938 .  
PRESEK_NJIVE                -0.0051977  0.0071563  -0.726   0.4676    
NOSILEC_STAR                 0.0026673  0.0093916   0.284   0.7764    
NOSILEC_SPOLŽ                0.2268010  0.3296174   0.688   0.4914    
KOPOP                       -2.5037627  0.5042230  -4.966 6.85e-07 ***
obtezba                      0.0005797  0.0034706   0.167   0.8673    
TIP_PISMA1:PRESEK_NJIVE     -0.0147345  0.0096077  -1.534   0.1251    
TIP_PISMA2:PRESEK_NJIVE     -0.0066239  0.0093269  -0.710   0.4776    
TIP_PISMA1:KOPOP             0.1683234  0.8157370   0.206   0.8365    
TIP_PISMA2:KOPOP             1.2030056  0.6349446   1.895   0.0581 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

I calculated average marginal effects specifically for the conditional part of the model where the interaction was significant, using marginaleffects package. Firstly, the average marginal effects in the different subgroups surprised me, as they are very high, so I'm wondering if I made some error in the specification of marginal effects?
    > avg_comparisons(m2023_a, variables="TIP_PISMA", by="KOPOP", type="conditional")

      Term                 Contrast KOPOP  Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S
 TIP_PISMA mean(1) - mean(Kontrola)     0     0.567      1.336  0.425    0.671 0.6
 TIP_PISMA mean(1) - mean(Kontrola)     1 -1458.598   2620.719 -0.557    0.578 0.8
 TIP_PISMA mean(2) - mean(Kontrola)     0    -1.143      0.752 -1.519    0.129 3.0
 TIP_PISMA mean(2) - mean(Kontrola)     1 -1461.145   2620.475 -0.558    0.577 0.8
    2.5 %   97.5 %
    -2.05    3.186
 -6595.11 3677.916
    -2.62    0.331
 -6597.18 3674.892

Columns: term, contrast, KOPOP, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
Type:  conditional 

Furthermore, when I test the hypothesis that the effect of treatment group 2 differs depending on the KOPOP covariate (b3-b1=0), the effect of the interaction term is not only non-significant, but also points into a different direction than the regression coefficient. I am not sure how to report and interpret these results along with significance from regression in a paper - Can I say that our treatment had any an effect on those participants that are in KOPOP or not?
> avg_comparisons(m2023_a, variables="TIP_PISMA", by="KOPOP", hypothesis="b3-b1=0", type="conditional")

    Term Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
 b3-b1=0    -1.71       1.29 -1.32    0.186 2.4 -4.24  0.824

Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
Type:  conditional 

Thanks for any help with the interpretation!

It's extremely hard to interpret individual regression coefficients when there are interactions. With the default treatment/dummy coding in R, the model summary() reports each single-predictor coefficient for a situation in which all of its interacting predictors are at reference or 0 values. Sometimes that isn't even a realistic situation, as when a continuous interactor has actual values far from the 0 to which they are extrapolated. With an interaction, it's certainly possible to have a "non-significant" result at those reference conditions but an important "significant" result when the values of the interacting predictors are different. For example, when you say

the treatment (TIP_PISMA) has no significant effect on the dependent variable

that's only true when both of its interacting predictors, PRESEK_NJIVE and KOPOP, are at their reference levels.
I'd recommend to focus on the specific hypotheses that you had in mind to test at the outset of the study, and not to worry about any of the lower-level coefficients for predictors involved in interaction terms.
If you want a broader overview of the significance of the individual predictors and interactions, consider the Anova() function in the car package, whose default Type II analysis nicely combines all the levels of each of your multi-level categorical predictors and of the interaction terms. You also can perform joint Wald tests on all terms involving a predictor, sometimes called "chunk tests". That way, correlated predictors can work together to document significant associations with outcome that would be missed by single-predictor analyses.
Finally, I'm not sure about the coding of your calls to avg_comparisons(); that's probably too software-specific to be on-topic here.

(+1) There may also be some theoretical justification for why the effects behave this way that OP hasn't considered. I give an example in this answer.
